# Get Firebase storage Ref path from download url

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Hi I want to clarify whether Firebase storage ref path can be obtained from the download url for the purpose of security

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the object path is embedded right there in the download URL, which you can see if you examine it carefully.  There is even an [API that converts a download URL into a reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#reffromurl).

Comment: Is there any equivalent API for Node.js Admin SDK?
I can't find it in the docs, please help.